# `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-voice

I want to add a voice search feature into my app, and I need to be able to convert speech to text, So I use the library

```
@react-native-community/voice
```

But I get This error,

```
 WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.
 WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.
```

It was working in the past on React Native .63, The name of the package was,

```
react-native-voice
```

But now I face a problem when I am using React Native .67

I appreciate anyone who will help me, And I have another question. Is there another better library for converting speech to text?

finally here is my code, that was working on React Native .63, But now it doesn't work.

```
import Voice from 'react-native-voice';

const App = () => {
  const [pitch, setPitch] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [end, setEnd] = useState('');
  const [started, setStarted] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [partialResults, setPartialResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Setting callbacks for the process status
    Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = onSpeechPartialResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = onSpeechVolumeChanged;

    return () => {
      //destroy the process after switching the screen
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    };
  }, []);

  const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
    //Invoked when .start() is called without error
    console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);
    setStarted('√');
  };

  const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer stops recognition
    console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
    setEnd('√');
  };

  const onSpeechError = (e) => {
    //Invoked when an error occurs.
    console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
    setError(JSON.stringify(e.error));
  };

  const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer is finished recognizing
    console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e);
    setResults(e.value);
  };

  const onSpeechPartialResults = (e) => {
    //Invoked when any results are computed
    console.log('onSpeechPartialResults: ', e);
    setPartialResults(e.value);
  };

  const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
    //Invoked when pitch that is recognized changed
    console.log('onSpeechVolumeChanged: ', e);
    setPitch(e.value);
  };

  const startRecognizing = async () => {
    //Starts listening for speech for a specific locale
    try {
      await Voice.start('ar-EG');
      setPitch('');
      setError('');
      setStarted('');
      setResults([]);
      setPartialResults([]);
      setEnd('');
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const stopRecognizing = async () => {
    //Stops listening for speech
    try {
      await Voice.stop();
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const cancelRecognizing = async () => {
    //Cancels the speech recognition
    try {
      await Voice.cancel();
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const destroyRecognizer = async () => {
    //Destroys the current SpeechRecognizer instance
    try {
      await Voice.destroy();
      setPitch('');
      setError('');
      setStarted('');
      setResults([]);
      setPartialResults([]);
      setEnd('');
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Same issue for RNLocation

Answer (score 0):

I just add two function to main java  module:

```
// Required for rn built in EventEmitter Calls.
@ReactMethod
public void addListener(String eventName) {

}

@ReactMethod
public void removeListeners(Integer count) {

}
```